# Cypress.io: Why is cy.route not setting a cookie?

Tags: cookies, http-headers, httpresponse, cypress

I have a cypress test. I want to set the cookies in the response header when the page requests a particular url.

I achieve this using `cy.route()` and `cy.setCookies'.

However, the cookie is not set if I attempt to set the cookie with `cy.route` in the headers object. In contrast, other headers are added when I set them in the headers object in `cy.route`.

I am curious. Why is this?

```
  it('Diverts user', () => {
    cy.server()
    cy.setCookie('sessionid','190912')
    cy.route({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/pay',
      response: {},
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html', // This is set
        'Set-Cookie': '999' // This is not set
      }
    })
   cy.url.should('eq', '/payment-successful')
})
```